# What brake pads and discs for my 2006 Citroen C4 1.6 VTR+?

Tags: brakes, part-identification, citroen

I have a 2006 Citroen C4 1.6 VTR+ (5 doors).

I need to change the brake discs and pads so I ordered those parts from [this website](http://www.carparts4less.co.uk/). I took them to a garage to get them fit, but they told me the parts are not correct; they are too big. I contacted the website and they will exchange them.

But first, I need to know how to know exactly the parts for my car.

#### The details of the (incorrect) brake discs:

Front:

- Thickness [mm]: 26,0
- Type: Internally Vented
- Centering Diameter [mm]: 66
- Diameter [mm]: 283
- Height [mm]: 34
- Hole Arrangement / Number: 04 / 06
- Minimum Thickness [mm]: 24
- Pitch Circle Ø [mm]: 108

Rear:

- Thickness [mm]: 9,0
- Type: Full
- Centering Diameter [mm]: 71
- Diameter [mm]: 246,5
- Height [mm]: 35
- Hole Arrangement / Number: 04 / 06
- Minimum Thickness [mm]: 8
- Pitch Circle Ø [mm]: 108

#### What are the correct brake pads and discs?

Comment: Can you give us some more information about your car? I see there are different models for the C4, namely is it a three door, or five door? Is it the coupe, Picasso, or Grand Picasso? What exactly did the mechanic say was "too big"? Was the diameter too big or was it too thick? Which ones exactly did you buy?

Comment: @Paulster2 is the 5-door hatchback. The diameter was too big. I checked and approx. it's 10 inches the front disc, and 9 inches the rear one (I measured it with the wheel on).

Comment: I'm seeing two different sizes, 266mm and 283mm. Do you know which one you bought? Do you have the part number? Since the discs are too big, the pads are probably the wrong ones as well. Don't know for sure, but you should probably have that checked as well.

Comment: Sorry, those sizes are for the front end.

Comment: @Paulster2 I added the specifications of the discs I bought that doesn't fit.

Comment: Well, the rear disks are the smaller ones. The front ones are the larger ones. I'd have the rear ones double checked before you return them, but it would appear the front ones will have to be replaced. To be sure, you could also just ask the mechanic which ones you should have purchased.

Comment: @Paulster2 I just email the garage with your suggestion.. I'll wait to see what do they say. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your engine please. Do you have petrol or diesel engine? How many kw/Hp is your engine?

It would be helpful to know the exact month and year your car was made. ***C4 model parts were updated in October, 2006.*** That may be your issue. You may have searched for parts from 10/06+, but your car spec is from before that date.

Discs for `2006 Citroen C4`s made before October 2006 should be following:

FRONT OEM numbers:

- 4246W1
- 424916
- 424983
- 4246W7
- 424915 (Dimensions: 266x22)

REAR OEM numbers:

- 424919
- 424932 (Dimensions: 249x9).

You should be able to find them at your parts dealer with these numbers.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The engine is 1.6 petrol and it was registered in January 2006 I think it's 110bhp

Comment: ok, I´ll try to get the answer to you asap

Comment: this should be your engine: 1.6 16V 80Kw NFU (TU5JP4), can you confirm?

Comment: I think you are right. but I don't have the papers with me right now. Looking in the Wikipedia it seems the only possible.

Comment: I have just edited my answer, it should be correct, simply you can measure your old discs by rules (or smthng else), and there should be apparent if front discs diameter is 266 and not 283 (simply remove front/wheel at one side to have better access to brake disc), apply the same procedure at rear and you should be 100% sure after that.

Comment: Thanks @Mustafa105. Can I ask how did you found those numbers? I'll try to measure it later today

Comment: I am psychic :D just kidding, I am using my parts dealer website http://www.autodily-sklad.cz/, but it´s in czech so you won´t understand that possibly, but I believe there a many resources where you can find this kind of info, for example, just be simple search I have found this for you http://www.bestpartstore.co.uk/citroen-c4/c4-lc/18333/10132